# I cannot show the google maps on iOS when I used the flutter to development

Tags: flutter, flutter-ios

I cannot show the google maps on iOS when I used the flutter to development.

I don't know why it cannot show it, but can show marker icon....

the function can running in Android, but cannot running in iOS

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your API key must persist the properties for using the iOS platform.

So, enabling Maps SDK for iOS platform should work.

Also, check your installed XCode and target sdk version: it must be higher that 12.0

Here is the [documentation link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/overview)

Comment: in my project, I had add `GMSServices.provideAPIKey("GoogleAPIKey")` into AppDelegate

Comment: Found the issues, forgot enable Maps SDK for iOS in GCP